# Can anybody identify what insect laid these eggs? Find in my backyard in N. Texas

Tags: species-identification

I happened to turn over this leaf in my backyard and found these eggs[image].  Would really like to know what they're from. I'm in North Texas.

Comment: Maybe https://springfieldmn.blogspot.com/2018/11/fuzz-on-kale.html